# Clear and delete S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to clear and delete and S3 bucket. I have access and verified that I can delete a single object out of the bucket. I'm using aws-sdk-ruby.

I'm calling `!delete` on the bucket and getting the following error:

```
[AWS S3 400 0.681157 0 retries] list_object_versions(:bucket_name=>"filepicker_sd_output/5CVImJfOTJmVUIlCzC1g_bigbird/thumbnails",:max_keys=>1000) AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidRequest There is no such thing as the ?versions sub-resource for a key

AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidRequest: There is no such thing as the ?versions sub-resource for a key
```

Here's the method I'm using: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb#L476

What does this even mean?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I shouldn't be looking to delete the bucket, I really need to focus on objects with a certain prefix and delete them.